Query Function - Label - Pivot - Google Sheet
How do I change the header from "Q1 FY25 quotient(sum Billable Hrssum(sum Billable Hrssum Non-Billable Hrs))" to "Q1 FY25" only just by tweaking the formula below? BTW I am using Google sheet.
"Select P, L, SUM(I)/(SUM(I)+SUM(J))
Where (L = 'Role1' OR L = 'Role2' OR L = 'Role3' OR L = 'Role4') AND (NOT P = 'Studio4') AND N is not null AND O = 'FY25'
Group by P, L
Pivot N
Label P 'Studio', L 'Role'")```



Please [edit] the title of your question to be descriptive, unambiguous, and specific to what you are asking. For more guidance, see How do I write a good title?.

Add the expression in select to the list of expressions in label, like this:
  "select P, L, sum(I) / (sum(I) + sum(J))
   where (L = 'Role1' or L = 'Role2' or L = 'Role3' or L = 'Role4') 
   and P <> 'Studio4' and N is not null and O = 'FY25'
   group by P, L
   pivot N
   label P 'Studio', L 'Role', sum(I) / (sum(I) + sum(J)) 'Q1 FY25' "

See label at the query language help page.
